# how to pass dynamic arguments into functions , instead of hardcoded strings

Tags: webdriver-io

We are facing an issue while trying to pass argument stored in var .
    The issue is we are storing the dynmically retrived div id in a variable and then passing it to .moveToObject function.

```
But the function throws back error ;
Error: invalid selector: No selector specified

Wanted to know how we can pass arguments stored in variables into various functions.

For instance in the code below , we are retiring sectionId via execute , storing it in sectionId variable .
then using it later on in moveToObject.

all functions seems to work when we are giving arguments inside "" quotes, but in our case we cannot do this. Please help us out how we can achieve this.

it('drag and drop should work', function() {
            var sectionId = "";
            // load page, then call function()
            return driver
                .url('http://localhost:9000')
                .pause(7000)
                .click('#layoutWizardButton')
                .click('#tableWizardBuild')
                .pause(3000)
                .execute(function() {
                        sectionId = window.document.getElementById('Section1');
                    }
                    .moveToObject('#ribbon-radio-tile')
                    .buttonDown()
                    .moveToObject(sectionId) -- -- > errors out here
                    .buttonUp()
                    .pause(2000)
                    .end()
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.moveToObject(sectionId.value)`